# Need to loop through two loops and use delayed iterations in the inner loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to do is build a way to loop through two `for` loops, but the inner loop needs to have a delay on each iteration, but it can't be a queued animation.

The way I'd like for this to work is, on start it would trigger each of the elements at an interval but not wait for their animations to finish. Then it goes to the next row of items (first loop iterating) and starts that row before all items are faded out in the previous row.

```
    var colLeng = Layout.columns,
        elemLeng,
        columnElements;

    // get number of columns
    for (var i = 0; i < colLeng; i++) {
        columnElements = $('.prvwImg[data-col="' + i + '"]');
        elemLeng = columnElements.length;

        for (var t = 0; t < elemLeng; t++) {
            columnElements.eq(t).delay(500 * t).fadeOut(400);
            //columnElements.eq(t).delay(500 * t).stop().fadeOut(400);
        }
    }
```

Edit: With this code it loops through fine, but the delay doesn't actually work so they fade out all at the same time.

Comment: What is it currently doing that you don't want it to do? What is it currently NOT doing that you DO want it to do?

Comment: @KevinB it appears to loop through fine, but the delay doesn't actually work so they fade out all at the same time.

Comment: The way i see it, all columns should start fading out at once, but each element in each column should fade one at a time. You want to also only fade one column at a time, right? You would have to add the `i` from the outer loop to the delay in the same way you are adding `t`

Comment: Yes that's about right, but I want each column is also slightly offset in time so that it fades gradually (the start of each column comes slightly after the previous column).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another delay based on each column.

```
columnElements.delay(500 * i)
```

This will result in a total delay on each column element of `500*i + 500*t`

Comment: like this? http://jsbin.com/exutaz/4/edit or do you want to get rid of the angled load and do one column at a time one row at a time